# Integer addition in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Here is my simple shell code. I want the result to be 2.Shell treats everything as a string.
How can i get this done ?

```
num=1
num=$(( $num + 1 ))
```

EDIT :

Complete code : Whats wrong in this if i want to print from 1 to 10 ?

```
#! /bin/bash

num=1
until test $num -eq 10
do
    num=$(( $num + 1 ))
    echo $num
done
```

Comment: Change `until test num -eq 10` to `until test $num -eq 10`! Its all about $$!!

Comment: Firstly, first time you echo num its already 2, so change `num=1` to `num=0` that should print all the numbers b/w 1 & 10 inclusive of 1 & 10 + the correction provided by Fredrik

Comment: Deleting this would be unfair to the people who took their time to answer your question.

Answer (score 18):

In `bash`, you don't need to do anything special:

```
$ num=1
$ num=$(( $num + 1 ))
$ echo $num
2
```

Comment: Worth pointing out `$` on variables` are optional and will be flagged by [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net} when included. `num=$(( num + 1 ))` is POSIX compliant and will not generate any issues.

Answer (score 3):

@tonio; please don't advocate using subshell (` ...  or $( ... ) ) constructs when they're not needed (to keep confusion to the maximum, $(( ... )) is not a sub-shell construct). Sub-shells can make a tremendous performance hit even with rather trivial amounts of data. The same is true for every place where an external program is used to do somethign that could be done with a shel built-in.

Example:

```
    num=1
    time while [[ $num -lt 10000 ]]; do
            num=$(( num+1 ))
    done
    echo $num
    num=1
    time while /bin/test $num -lt 10000; do
            num=$( /bin/expr $num + 1 )
    done
    echo $num
```

Output (run in ksh on Linux):

```
real    0m0.04s
user    0m0.04s
sys     0m0.01s
10000

real    0m20.32s
user    0m2.23s
sys     0m2.92s
10000
```

...so run-time factor of 250, and CPU-time factor of 100. I admit the example I used was a exaggerated one, with explicitly requiring all built-ins to be bypassed, but I think the point was made: creating new processes is expenisve, avoid it when you can, and know your shell to recognise where new processes are created.

Comment: In my system (Debian) **test** and **expr** are in **/usr/bin** instead.

Comment: The path issues are another reason to favor shell built-ins, over external executables. Even the Linux sector is so fragmented (the example code was written on a Slackware system).

Comment: You can omit double brackets by using `let`: `let num=num+1` or `let num++`.

Comment: Although "/usr/bin/test" and "/bin/test" will spawn a new shell, "test" is a builtin in most modern shells.  Any shell in which test is not a built in will likely spawn a sub-shell to run "[", so this is not an argument that favors "[" over "test".

Comment: @William; yes, but my point here was to demonstrate how expensive it is to build on extenral program execution, like the solution presented by tonio did (even though it was a functionally working solution), so I took use of external programs to the extreme - and on the other hand, I provided the same solution using shell built-ins.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
num=1; ((num++)); echo $num
2
```

or

```
num=1; echo $((++num))
2
```

for loops

```
for num in {1..10}; do echo $num; done
```

or (in bash at least)

```
for ((num=1; num<=10; num++)) { echo $num; }
```

second loop more useful when more programming involved:

```
for (( num=1,mun=10; num<=10; num++,mun--)) { echo $num $mun; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You just did:

```
$ num=1; num=$(( $num + 1 ));echo $num
2
```

***Note***: You don't need to quote variables inside `$(( ))`. Also, you can just use `$((num++))`

Answer (score 1):

You are not specifying which shell you are using, but the most concise form I know is this one (works at least in bash):

```
num=$[num+1]
```

If only incrementing by one and changing the variable itself rather than printing/assigning, then:

```
((num++))
```

Is a better/more elegant solution. See dogbane's answer for that.

If looping over the values, I would use this form instead:

```
for i in `seq 1 10`; do
   echo $i
done
```

Comment: for looping I'd prefer `{1..10}` instead of invoking `seq`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$ num=1; num=`expr $num + 1`; echo $num;
```

EDIT:

More efficient would be:

```
num=$(( num + 1 ))
```

Thanks @Charles Duffy for your comment.

Comment: i have checked it it works num=1; num=`expr $num + 1`; echo $num;

Comment: Works, yes. Efficient, no. `num=$(( num + 1 ))` is tens if not hundreds of times faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use `((num++))` as shorthand for incrementing `num`.

```
$ num=1
$ ((num++))
$ echo $num
2
```

Answer (score -1):

works for me

```
$ num=1
$ num=$(( $num + 1 ))
$ echo $num
2
```

What output do you get?

Read more about bash Arithmetic @ [tldp](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html)

## EDIT

To do something 10 times in bash you can use (using [brace-expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion)}

```
$ for i in {1..10}; do echo $i; done
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

However, you cannot use variables between the `{}`. If this is the case, use `seq` instead.